# iphone app on iphone 6 every now and then switches to background

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am in the process of testing one of my apps. It works fine on iphone 4s and 5. On iphone 6 however, my tester is reporting that every now and then the app goes to background and he need to relaunch. I would assume it is crashing but he is not able to replicate it (which means there is something really wrong).

Any idea how to go about figuring out what's going on there? All three phones are on ios 9.0.2 all code base is Swift 2.0.

Comment: How is it distributed? TestFlight? Just email? AppStore? Other? The reason I ask is that you need to somehow get hold of the crash log to see what is happening. The method of getting the crash log depends on how it was distributed.

Comment: Loaded from laptop...the thing I'm after is not how to access crash log but rather if anyone knows of 'known issues' with Swift 2.0, ios 9+ and iPhone 6 plus.

Comment: If there were problems like that you wouldn't be the first to find out. It would be all over the news etc... Lol. Find the crash log. Fix the bug. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could add Crashlytics. I included a link below.  It works really well.  It will send you crash reports with a stack trace.

[Crashlytics Link](https://try.crashlytics.com/)